# Strange validation error messages

Tags: django, django-forms, validation

I'm using the standard authentication form. It's clean method looks like this :

```
def clean(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
    password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

    if username and password:
        self.user_cache = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if self.user_cache is None:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields are case-sensitive."))
        elif not self.user_cache.is_active:
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("This account is inactive."))

    # TODO: determine whether this should move to its own method.
    if self.request:
        if not self.request.session.test_cookie_worked():
            raise forms.ValidationError(_("Your Web browser doesn't appear to have cookies enabled. Cookies are required for logging in."))

    return self.cleaned_data
```

My login form :

```
<form method="post" action="{% url django.contrib.auth.views.login %}">
    <table>
        {% if form.errors %}
            <tr class="form-errors">
                <td>
                    <ol>
                        {% for error in form.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ol>
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
```

But instead of the validation messages I get :

if username and pass is incorrect or account is inactive : "`1. __all__`"
if password is not given : "`1. password`"
if username is not given : "`1. username`"
if both are not given : "`1. username 2. password`"
no message for incorrect username

**EDIT:**
If I change

```
                <td>
                    <ol>
                        {% for error in form.errors %}
                            <li>{{ error }}</li>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </ol>
                </td>
```

to :

{{ form.errors }}

I receive i.e `__all__ and beneath it "Account inactive"`. How to get just the message ?
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. form.errors is a dictionary, so like every dictionary you can read key and value. Key is field or `__all__`' and value is the error message you were looking for.

```
{% if form.errors %}
<tr>
    {% for k, v in form.errors.items %}
    <td>{{k}}</td>
    <td>{{v}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endif %}
```

**EDIT**

If you wan't to select specific field error types :

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for k, v in form.errors.items %} 
        <tr>
            {% ifequal k 'password' %}
                <td>Password</td>
                {% else %}
                    {% ifequal k 'username' %}
                        <td>Username</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td>Other</td>
            {% endifequal %}{% endifequal %}                
            <td>{{v}}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

or select `'__all__'` in ifequal .